# Does the HERE batch geocoding job request response take longer when there are more locations?

Tags: geocoding, here-api

After starting a new batch geocoding job ([step one here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/request-submit.html)), does the amount of time it takes to get a response ([step two here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/request-submit.html)) depend on the amount of individual geocode requests? (ie. does it take longer to get a response for 10,000 locations VS 10 locations?)

On a similar note, what are the different possible statuses that can be returned in the response? (for instance, "accepted" in [step two here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/request-submit.html))

I tried looking for these answers in the HERE batch geocoding documentation, but couldn't find anything.

The [HERE API FAQ page](https://developer.here.com/faqs) directed me here for any technical support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is a bigger infrastructure in the backend of the BGC and job items are processed in parallel to some degree, not all items of a batch job can be processed in parallel at the same time. So yes, it takes longer for bigger jobs.

A batch job can be in one of the following states:

**submitted**

A batch job was submitted to the batch system and is ready to be started. The batch job can be started by the user by sending the HTTP PUT "action=run" request.

**accepted**

Batch job has been verified for correctness and validity and has been added to the queue, waiting to be scheduled for execution.

**running**

Job is being processed now.

**complete**

Job processing completed.

**cancelled**

Job has been cancelled by user with HTTP PUT command action=cancel.

**deleted**

Job was deleted by user with HTTP DELETE command

**failed**

Job failed while running. This is unusual and caused by an internal error. You can try to restart the job with a PUT request and action=run or delete the job.

[State transition graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgoAB.png)