# HERE Batch Geocoder Accepted but never Finishes

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I've been evaluating moving our Mapping and Routing apps to use HERE's Rest API.  I've been testing some scenarios to proof it out and one I can't seem to get working correctly is the Batch Geocoding.

The submission of the data to Geocode works fine and I do get a valid RequestID back but when I poll for the status of the Batch Job the status always says "accepted" but never seems to change.

I am using a developer account that has a 90 day trial. Could there be a limitation due to the type of account?

Comment: Ok, this question appears to be about the API and the features of the trial account, which is [outside the scope of SE questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also you're more likely to get a valid response if your question provides enough useful details (see the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide)

Comment: Since HERE directs you on their site to this section for HERE API questions, I figured this would be the correct place to find someone who knows something.  Secondly, this is simply based on running the example on their API documentation page... so really no more information is needed.

Comment: May this help ... A batch job was submitted to the batch system and is ready to be started. The batch job can be started by the user by sending the HTTP PUT "action=run" request. From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724555/does-the-here-batch-geocoding-job-request-response-take-longer-when-there-are-mo/47830001#47830001

Comment: This looks like an ongoing issue to me. I too am not proceeding past the accepted status. The accepted status is received after the POST with the variable "action=run". There is no ability to execute a "run" once again unless you re-post - then you just get a new job id - which never runs. I have a feeling it is something to do with account limits but I have also tried across various accounts. I am currently waiting for HERE to come back to me - did you get anywhere @DaveVanderWekke

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a queue issue, except mine has been going on for nearly a week.
[HERE API never runs batch job, always returns accepted status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104628/here-api-never-runs-batch-job-always-returns-accepted-status/46196810#46196810)

Comment: It was a queue issue. Did not hear from HERE but all the jobs suddenly completed simultantously. Service has been working fine ever since.